# Nonstandard quotation margins

Tags: indentation, double-sided, quoting

I would like to create a document with nonstandard quotation environment.

[image]

The goal is that on odd pages quotations have to be indent on the left, and on even pages in opposite way (indent on the right).

**EDIT:**

The  [Thomas F. Sturm's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/30617/thomas-f-sturm) solution works well, but there is a problem with footnotes inside the myquotation box (see my [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/124546/tcolorbox-footnote-on-page-on-which-there-are)). Do you have another idea how to solve this task?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like that?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,changepage}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage[top=2cm,bottom=2cm,left=2cm,right=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{myquotation}{%
  blank,breakable,parbox=false,check odd page,left=2cm,
  toggle left and right}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-4]

\begin{myquotation}
\lipsum[1-4]
\end{myquotation}

\lipsum[1-2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hehe! I was doing almost the exact same thing!

Comment: Should not `csquotes` be preferred here?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Seldom enough that I am faster than you ;-)

Comment: @pluton I cannot say if `csquotes` has such a feature. It has a lot of features, but I could not find this one on a quick scan over the documentation.

Comment: can't that widow be avoided, please?

Comment: @barbarabeeton No, I fear that is not possible automatically. In the background, `\vsplit` is working and currently I see no automated way to get it controlling widows and orphans.